# Aligning Text in CSS/JS menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to align the text in the menu at:
http://crango.uofydating.com/dir/New2.html

- In the 1st tab, I want there to be a line break after "Item".
- In the 2nd and 3rd tab, I want there to be a line break after "This is".

I only posted the part of the menu that I need help with, so it may look a bit odd. But it is connected to some Javascript code which makes it more challenging to edit. The JS can't be removed.

Comment: So why not just put line breaks in?  like: `Item<br />#1` ?

Comment: Here it is with the line breaks: http://crango.uofydating.com/dir/New3.html (it's fine until you click on one of the links)

Comment: can you post js code??

Comment: The JS code is at http://crango.uofydating.com/dir/aria.js

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to a fiddle? The code / page you're hosting may go down in the future, but a fiddle will still be accessible to future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution

I have created a fiddle for you

```
Use .html() instead of .text()
```

CODE:

```
.html('<strong>' + $(this).find('a').html() + '</strong>')
```

It works great ;)

Check it

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/yL6Tn/1/

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your js code, you are setting back to your original text inside strong tags with .html inside the .click method. So just insert the line break in there. 
Insert break in this line in your js:

```
 .html('<strong>' + $(this).text() + '</strong>')
```